# How to get CMake to generate TypeSupport files such as <idl_file>Support.[cxx,h]?

Tags: cmake, publish-subscribe, data-distribution-service, rti-dds

I am using CMake to generate files from an IDL and placing them in a library on RedHat. Problem is, the <idl_file>Support[c,h] files are not being generated so I can't register type support. In CMake, I have the following line which generates the <idl_file>Plugin.[c,h] and <idl_file>.[cxx,h] files. The problem is, it's not generating any <idl_file>Support.[cxx,h] files.

```
connextdds_rtiddsgen_run(IDL_FILE myFile.idl LANG "C++11")
```

As far as I know, I'm not using these as standalone by creating a library with them inside, am I? I did not use NDDS_STANDALONE_TYPE, nor add ndds_standalone_type.cxx.

If I use the following command-line, the <idl_file>Support[c,h] files will show up.

```
rtiddsgen -namespace myFile.idl
```

However, if I manually add the *Plugin.[c,h], *Support.[c,h], and *.[c.h] files and compile into a lib, then link against it w/ my program, there are a lot of undefined references such as:

```
myns::myTypePlugin_serialize_to_cdr_buffer(char*, unsigned int*, myns::myType const*) myns::myTypeSeq::length() const
myns::myTypePluginSupport_create_data_w_params(myns::myType*, DDS_TYPEDeallocationParams_t const*)
myns::myTypePluginSupport_create_data_w_params(DDS_TypeAllocationParams_t const*)
```

And so I'm trying to get CMake to do this work for me hoping for a better outcome. How would I make CMake generate these TypeSupport files?

Comment: According to the [source](https://github.com/rticommunity/ros-data-types/blob/master/resources/cmake/ConnextDdsCodegen.cmake), the function `connextdds_rtiddsgen_run` effectively creates a **custom command**, which is able to produce files listed in `*_SOURCES` and `*_HEADERS` variables (exact name of variables see in the docs). It should be some **target** which depends on these files. Otherwise, none will be generated. Usually, such target is created with `add_executable`/`add_library` and lists given files as its sources. But you could create any custom target which DEPENDS on these files.

Comment: I'm using the ConnextDdsCodegen.cmake file directly from RTI and hence, the <idl>_CXX11_GENERATED_SOURCES variable and while it contains the files I get above, it does not include the <idl>Support.[cxx,h] file.

Comment: According to the [source](https://github.com/rticommunity/ros-data-types/blob/master/resources/cmake/ConnextDdsCodegen.cmake#L279), the files `Support.cxx` and `Support.h` are added to the `*_SOURCES` and `*_HEADERS` lists for **C++** language, but I see no such addition for **C++11** language which you use. If these files are **actually** created, then given CMake script is probably wrong, feel free to report the error to developers. (I am not an expert in IDL, so I cannot say for sure whether given files should be generated and whether they should be used.)

Comment: @Tsyvarev - if you'd like to make that an answer, I'll mark it. C++ does generate the needed files, but C++11 I'm thinking is not supposed to. I'll follow up w/ them about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the script [ConnextDdsCodegen.cmake](https://github.com/rticommunity/ros-data-types/blob/master/resources/cmake/ConnextDdsCodegen.cmake#L279), which defines `connextdds_rtiddsgen_run` function, it is expected that files `*Support.cxx` and `*Support.h` will be generated for **C++** language:

```
list(APPEND sources "${path_base}Plugin.cxx" "${path_base}Support.cxx")
list(APPEND headers "${path_base}Plugin.h" "${path_base}Support.h")
```

but I see no addition of these files in case of **C++11** language.

Probably this means that given files (`*Support.cxx` and `*Support.h`) won't be generated for C++11 (and for C++03 too).